# Enviar valores de input file por VueJS y axios

Tags: php, laravel, ajax, vue.js, axios

Estoy intentando realizar el envio de la información de un input file para el guardado de videos, sin embargo, al momento de enviar el objeto por medio de Vue y axios recibo el nombre del archivo, pero no el objeto completo.

El input que estoy utilizando es el siguiente, y con el método change realizo las peticiones al servidor

```
<input type="file" multiple id="video-files" style="display: none;" ref="videos" @change="upload">
```

y el componente de Vue es el siguiente:

```
Vue.component('channel-uploads', {
   props:{
       channel: {
           type: Object,
           required:true,
           default: () => ({})
       }
   },
   data: () => ({
       selected: false,
       videos: []
   }),
   methods: {
       upload(){
           this.selected = true;
           this.videos = Array.from(this.$refs.videos.files);

           const uploaders = this.videos.map(video => {
               const formData = new FormData();
               console.log(video)
               formData.append('video', video);
               formData.append('title', video.name);
               return axios.post(`/channels/${this.channel.id}/videos`, formData)
               .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
               .catch((err) => console.log(err));
           })
       }
   }
})
```

El envió de información funciona correctamente, a excepción del envió del objeto del input file.

El resultado devuelto es el siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque usas ref y jquery en lugar de usar un v-model y vue como corresponde?

Comment: Estoy empezando con el tema de vue y de manera autodidacta, realmente es la manera en que estoy aprendiendo a usarlo, he estado siguiendo un ejemplo donde funciona, sin embargo, por algún motivo me envia el objeto vacio.

Comment: El ejemplo que estas siguiendo no es bueno. En la pagina de vue, la documentacion es muy clara y hay componentes ya escritos que te devuelven un objeto con todo el archivo que necesitas. Revisa vue.com y tambien busca awesome vue para los componentes. Todo te resultara mas simple